# How to read files from S3 bucket in glue by using a partial name of the file

Tags: amazon-s3, pyspark, aws-glue

I am trying to read files from s3 bucket in Glue based on the keyword search on file names. For example, read a file if the file name contains "file". This is the code I am currently using to read a given file from s3 bucket.

```
File1_node = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(
    format_options={"quoteChar": '"', "withHeader": True, "separator": ","},
    connection_type="s3",
    format="csv",
    connection_options={
        "paths": [
            "s3:// env-files/data/material/filename1.csv"
        ],
        "recurse": True,
    },
    transformation_ctx=" File1_node",
)
 
File1= File1_node.toDF()
```

I want to read files dynamically by using keyword search. For example, if a file name contains "file" and there is a file named "filename1" then that file should be read. If there are multiple files that contains the same keyword then append them all. Please let me know if there is anyway to do so. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could do that using boto3 s3 [list_objects_v2()](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.list_objects_v2).

```
import boto3
from typing import List

s3_client = boto3.client('s3')

def get_all_filepaths(filename_filter: str, bucket: str, prefix: str) -> List[str]:
    response = s3_client.list_objects_v2(Bucket=bucket, Prefix=prefix)
    return [key['Key'] for key in response['Contents'] if filename_filter in key['Key']]

File1_node = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(
    format_options={"quoteChar": '"', "withHeader": True, "separator": ","},
    connection_type="s3",
    format="csv",
    connection_options={
        "paths": get_all_filepaths(filename_filter, bucket, prefix),
        "recurse": True,
    },
    transformation_ctx=" File1_node",
)
 
File1= File1_node.toDF()
```

Using this, you can get a list of paths that match your criteria. I haven't run this, but I think you should also append s3://, please check that. Also, if there are more than 1000 objects, you will have to implement the logic to continue fetching the data using `NextContinuationToken` from the response of the function call.

Hope this helps!